# How to validate a URL in Vee-validate 3.0?

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I don't find the option to validate a URL anymore.

What would be the best way to implement it or to add it to vee-validate 3.0?

I guess I have to extend the current vee-validate:

```
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, localize, extend as VeeExtend } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full';
```

and then something like

```
const urlFixRule = (value) => {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(value);
};
VeeExtend('url', {
    validate: (val) => urlFixRule(val),
    message: i18n.t('custom_vee_validate.incorrect_url')
});
```

- Which would be the best way of validating the URL?
- Why has such a useful feature been removed?

Answer (score 2):

@mojtaba answer is completly correct. Therefore we could improve on his answer on adding the rule globally available. This would allow to re-use the rule anywhere in our application

```
import { extend } from "vee-validate";

extend('url', {
  validate(value: string | null | undefined): boolean {
    if (value) {
      return /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(value);
    }

    return false;
  },
  message: 'This value must be a valid URL',
})
```

Then in our component we could simply do:

```
<input rules="url"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vee Validate has  **regex**  rule, as you know most of the validations are created by regular expiration. so you can easily create rules that you need without extending.

[Document Link](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html#rules)

Example for URL validating:

```
<ValidationProvider :rules="{ regex: /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ }" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input type="text" v-model="value">
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Comment: You cannot use pipes (|) inside regex as per the documentation but this works somehow!